# awk to print the line number of a closing bracket

Tags: awk

I have a file

### 1.txt

```
ejryheiur

rewurie

(

ejwhrejkrh

rewrhwe

rewkhrwe

rewhkr

)

dfhgsdfh

rqwergjweg

jhwgrh

(

rehgwrwhe


rhwejkr

)
```

### With this nawk script

```
   nawk '
       BEGIN { 
       count1=1  ;
       count2=0 ;
       }
       {
       if ((NR > 2) && ( $0 ~/(/) ) 
       {
            count1++ ;
            if ((NR > 2) && ($0 ~/)/)) 
            {
                count2++ ; 
                if (count1 == count2) 
                {
                  print NR ; 
                  exit 
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if ((NR > 2) && ($0 ~ /)/)) 
            {
                count2++ ; 
                if (count1 == count2) 
                {
                    print NR;
                    exit
                }
            }
        }
       }
   ' 1.txt
```

But I'm getting this error:

nawk: illegal primary in regular expression ( at
source line number 7 context is

```
if ((NR > 2) && ($0 >>>  ~/(/ <<< ))
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to help with if you put your script into a text file and did a little formatting.

Comment: Helping for free, Don't we deserve a bit more explanation i.e. //Quotes in the code ?? =P also Format your answer. Too hard to read..

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience , can you please help me

Comment: Did some additional formatting fixes...

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the round bracket in the regular expression.

Either with a backslash:

```
if ((NR > 2) && ( $0 ~/\(/) )
```

Or with square brackets:

```
if ((NR > 2) && ( $0 ~/[(]/) )
```

Comment: @Timson, not the answer you were looking for?  We can flesh this answer out, if you still have questions.